# Ajax won't post to PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a page that has 2 cascading Select using Ajax. The Ajax correctly populates the second Select, however when I go to post the data to MySQL using PHP i get an error that the field populated by AJAX is "Unidentified." The exact error is

> Notice: Undefined index: probcode in ..\input.php on line
>   21

It does post if the Ajax call is not made and the default select is still there. It only errors after AJAX has replaced the DIV.

I would like to add that it is like the from element disappears from PHP even though AJAX adds it to the form. Is there another PHP function I should use to post AJAX data to MySQL?

I do not know Jquery and am looking for a way to get this to work with just JavaScript at the moment (because of time and my lack of Jquery knowledge), however if there is an easy way to add Jquery to the existing code I would definitely be interested. Also i know the data is not secure going into MySQL at the moment, That will be addressed immediately after this. I am just working on a wire-frame of a specific function at the moment.

First the two selects.

```
            <tr>
                <td>Problem Type</td>
                <td><?php
                    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Failed");
                    mysql_select_db("test")or die("Connection Failed");
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM wfprobtype ORDER BY probtype ASC";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                    ?>
                    <select name="probtype" id="probtype" onchange="changeContent(this.value)">
                    <?php
                    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $line['ID'];?>" > <?php echo $line['probtype'];?> </option>
                    <?php
                    } 
                    mysql_close()
                    ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>Problem: </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="val2div">
                        <select name="probcode" id="probcode">
                            <option value="default"></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

This is what the Ajax calls to replace "val2div" val2.php

```
<?php
$val2=intval($_GET['val2']);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("test")or die("Connection Failed");
$query = "SELECT * FROM wfprobcode WHERE typeID='$val2' ORDER BY Probcode ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="probcode" id="probcode"  onchange="">
<?php
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['Probcode'];?>"> <?php echo $line['Probcode'];?> </option>
<?php
}
mysql_close()
?>
```

Ajax Script Dny.js

```
function changeContent(val)
{
if (val=="")
  // if blank, we'll set our innerHTML to be blank.
  {
  document.getElementById("val2div").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // new browser
  {  
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // new browser
      alert("newb");
  }
else // Old Browser
  {  
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 

  }
  // on state change
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  // if we get a good response from the webpage, display the output
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
      document.getElementById("val2div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
  }
 // GET file. 
xmlhttp.open("GET","val2.php?val2="+val, true);
xmlhttp.send();
 alert(val)
}
```

post to MySQL input.PHP

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("test", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO `test`.`test` (
    `ID`,
    `Dattime`, 
    `probtype`,
    `probcode`
    )
    VALUES(
    NULL,NOW(),'$_POST[probtype]','$_POST[probcode]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }

mysql_close($con); ?>
```

I am hoping I am just missing simple something at the moment. This is my first time working with Ajax. I really appreciate any and all help at the moment.

EDIT: - One final edit before I attempt to rewrite the whole thing. Is there a way that using Jquery I could fix this? If not does anyone have a down and dirty way to make it just full postback without the AJAX?

I really appreciate those that have contributed so far an anyone who has any ideas at all.

Thanks in Advance!

-D

Comment: When you `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` something in the table, you should use `mysql_unbuffered_query()` instead of `mysql_query()`

Comment: All your codes lead to obvious duplication

Comment: @metal_fan Why is unbuffered a better solution.

Comment: A quick and dirty fix to your problem `Notice: Undefined index: probcode in ..\input.php on line 21` - just disable error reporting at the top of the script, like, `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: @metal_fan I wish i could but I need that data to post to Mysql. It is like after the AJAX the form element disappears from PHP even though the AJAX does bring the the select box to the screen.

Comment: Did you mean id="probcode"  onchange="changeContent(this.value)">

Comment: @techie_28 I am not sure. Is there a better way to write the AJAX? The way it works now it will correctly replace the DIV"val2div: with the new select box. The problem is when updating MySql. It is like the Update PHP cannot see the new DIV when using firefox. This only occurs when I use firefox. When I use IE it works fine and updates the database. I have used firebug and I cannot find out when it fails. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the name probcode appears in the new populated select?And have you tried using $_POST['probcode']; instead of '$_POST[probcode]' you need to escape the string accordingly but give it a try.

Comment: @techie_28 I have escaped the strings to no avail and changed all the post. The end solution was to force the users to use IE. (Not that big of a deal in that environment, not ideal for me though.) It seems to be the only option. Its like the div elements no longer exists to Firefox & chrome after the ajax call completes and the solution is displayed. Firebug does see the new data though. It only fails when trying to submit the data to the database. PHP errors that the field specified doesn't exist, even thought the ajax call works perfectly for displaying the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the code endlessly I have found that the everything works fine when using IE with the code above! The issues are directly with Firefox interpreting the AJAX return.

Answer (score 0):

in val2.php you miss closinge element for select

```
 </select>
```

and I guess in input.PHP, it should better be `'{$_POST['probtype']}'` than `'$_POST[probtype]'`

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `test`.`test` (
`ID`,
`Dattime`, 
`probtype`,
`probcode`
)
VALUES(
NULL,NOW(),'{$_POST['probtype']}','{$_POST['probcode']}')";
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the select. Unfortunately that nor did changing the Post. It does take all fields that are not populated by ajax. For example it will post the default select option if I never pick a first option initiating the AJAX. It only fails to post the value from val2.php. It is almost like the input cannot see the change.